# How to only display the file difference between two folder recursively in a Unix command?

Tags: unix, recursion, directory, diff, subdirectory

A have 2 directory : dir1 and dir2. In the dir1 I have some pictures files and in the dir2 I have the same pictures files and more in many subdirectories.

I used :

```
diff --brief -r dir1/ dir2/
```

Output :

```
Only in /Users/Name/Pictures/Bibliothèque Photos.photoslibrary/Masters: 2013
Only in /Users/Name/Pictures/Bibliothèque Photos.photoslibrary/Masters: 2014
Only in /Users/Name/Pictures/Bibliothèque Photos.photoslibrary/Masters: 2015
Only in /Volumes/Data/Photo Compare: IMG_0002.JPG
Only in /Volumes/Data/Photo Compare: IMG_0003.PNG
Only in /Volumes/Data/Photo Compare: IMG_0004.JPG
Only in ...
```

But this only show me that folders in dir2 are not in dir1 and for dir1 the pictures files in dir1 are not on dir2.

But the only thing I want is the pictures files difference between these folders recursively.

Does anyone knows ?
I didn't find my solution on forums and so on...
I also tried to make my own script but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I agree with melpomene. Diff is used to compre text files, so exactly what are you expecting it to tell you? You may be more interested in **cmp**, if you're looking for binary differences.

Comment: I just want to see pictures that are only in one directory. And I want to make it search for picture also in folder and subfolders.

Comment: Like `diff -urNad dir1 dir2` then? Not a programming question anyway.

Comment: Something like `find dir1 dir2 -type f | sed 's#.*/##' | sort | uniq -c` ?